# Remove VisualEffectView from subview

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uivisualeffectview

I defined a `VisualEffectView` by using a boolean condition. In this case, when a button is pressed this function is called with `active: true`

```
func addVisualEffectView(active: Bool) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    if active {
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 2)
    } else {
        blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

In another button, this function is called again with `active: false`, it is supposed to remove `VisualEffectView` subview from the screen, but it doesn't. Could you help me and tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added it once, and then you call your function again, it will not remove the previously added view, it will just not add the new `UIVisualEffectView`. 
You need to be able to keep track of the view that you've created by keeping using its `tag` property.

```
func addVisualEffectView(active: Bool) {
    if active {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
        blurEffectView.tag = 332211
        self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 2)
    } else {
        self.view.viewWithTag(332211)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```